# Orderer and peer containers not starting.I am using hyperledger/fabric 2.0.0-alpha version

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

currently I am trying to run basic-network .after starting orderer its existing with following errors.

````
panic: [channel ordererchannel] config requires unsupported channel capabilities: Channel capability V2_0 is required but not supported: Channel capability V2_0 is required but not supported ```
I am using hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.0.0-alpha image
````

Answer (score 1):

Are using a modified version of the script and generating your own `genesis.block` and `channel.tx` ?

I have had the same error as you when I generate my own config files, but if I use the pre-generated config files then the orderer starts OK.

So far, my conclusion is that there is a problem with configtxgen not with the fabric-orderer 2.0.0 alpha, but more investigation required.

Comment: Thank you .I  am using modified version to generate  channel.tx .Also now fabric-orderer:2.0.0-alpha is working for  me after changing  capabilities for orderer  in configtx.yml file from v2_0 to v1_3

Answer (score 1):

- Hey, All you have to do is make sure the bin folder which is present under the fabric-samples/bin which has configtxgen is latest and 2.0.0 alpha version
- When you got checkout it just checks out the source code not the bin folder
- When you clone fabric-samples it just downloaded the source code not the bin folder as it contains more than 50MB, so a curl command would have done for you
- Please make sure that you have 2.0.0 alpha configtxgen bin file present and refer the same at channel capabilities